# .Net Maui Grid doesn't change after being updated

Tags: c#, grid, maui, .net-7.0

I'm new to .Net Maui and I'm stuck on a probably very stupid problem.

In a ContentPage, I defined a ScrollView and a Grid by parameterizing it with 4 columns, this is the XAML code:

```
    <ScrollView x:Name="scrollView">
    
        <Grid x:Name="tabella"
              ColumnDefinitions="*,2*,2*,*" 
              Margin="10,10,10,10" />

    </ScrollView>
```

When the page is loaded, it calls the Populate() method, here's the code:

```
    private void PopolaTabella(List<ClassPrenotazione> prenotazioni)
    {
        tabella.RowDefinitions.Clear();

        CreaIntestazione();

        int riga = 1;

        foreach (ClassPrenotazione prenotazione in prenotazioni)
        {
            AggiungiRiga(riga, prenotazione);
            riga++;
        }
        
        scrollView.ForceLayout();       
    }
```

And here's the CreaIntestazione() code:

```
    private void CreaIntestazione()
    {
        tabella.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition(60));

        tabella.Add(new Border
        {
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            Stroke = Brush.Black,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("f05924")
        }, 0, 0);
        tabella.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = "Nr.",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        }, 0, 0);

        tabella.Add(new Border
        {
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            Stroke = Brush.Black,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("f05924")
        }, 1, 0);
        tabella.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = "Data",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        }, 1, 0);

        tabella.Add(new Border
        {
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            Stroke = Brush.Black,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("f05924")
        }, 2, 0);
        tabella.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = "Orario",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        }, 2, 0);
    }
```

AggiungiRiga is the same of CreaIntestazione but with data.

When the page appears for the first time, everything works nice.

When an element is removed from "prenotazioni", the Populate() command is called again. At this point, the Grid does not change.

I have done many tests and the only result I have obtained is by changing `table.RowDefinitions.Clear();` with `table.Clear();` and adding `Content = table` as the last command.
In this way, the updated table is shown, but obviously scrolling no longer works.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The Grid control isn’t the optimal choice for your scenario.

If you want to show multiple data rows like in your table definition, you should use [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/?view=net-maui-7.0) together with an [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0).

Both are made to suit your needs. The two documentation links have plenty of usage samples and detailed explanations.

Hope this helps.